# Mui Text Field . When changing icon , it's not clickable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using a MUI Text Field component. I added a select prop so i make it a select with dropwon values and a dropdown icon . I wanted to change the dropdown Icon to a custom icon i have in figma . The problem is that when i chage it to a custom icon , i cannot click it anymore and i've tried multiple solutions like the one shown in the snippet below but it's still not clickable . This is happening for all my text field everywhere in the App . Can someone help me with this who has used MUI before and has dealt with this thing , thanks !

```js
/* eslint-disable react/jsx-props-no-spreading */
import React from 'react';
import { MenuItem, TextField } from '@mui/material';
import '../../assets/utils/_groupbySelect.scss';

const MuiSelect = ({
  label,
  value,
  disabled,
  onChange,
  children,
  defaultValue,
  withNoneOption,
  className,
}: MuiSelectProps) => {

  const NewIcon = (props) => (
    <svg
      {...props}
      style={{ width: '11px', height: '11px', marginTop: '2px' }}
      className="sorter-dropdown"
      width="8"
      height="5"
      viewBox="0 0 8 5"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path d="M1 1L4 3.5L7 1" stroke="#4C4C4D" strokeLinecap="round" />
    </svg>
  );

  return (
    <TextField
      select
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      label={label}
      disabled={disabled}
      className={className}
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
      variant="standard"
      SelectProps={{
        IconComponent: () => <NewIcon />,
      }}
      InputProps={{
        disableUnderline: true,
      }}
      fullWidth
      size="small"
    >
      {withNoneOption ? isNoneOption : children}
    </TextField>
  );
};
export default MuiSelect;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with `NewIcon` in your example code. Both of those issues prevent the application of the `className` prop that [MUI tries to provide to the icon component](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.10.12/packages/mui-material/src/Select/SelectInput.js#L546). The [styles that MUI applies](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.10.12/packages/mui-material/src/NativeSelect/NativeSelectInput.js#L90) cause the click to pass through the icon and cause the appropriate action on the select input (e.g. open/close the select).

The first issue is how you are using it:

```
IconComponent: () => <NewIcon />
```

In this code you are wrapping `NewIcon` with another component layer (via the arrow function), and that wrapper component is not passing any props along to `NewIcon`, so the `className` prop from MUI never gets there. You should remove this wrapper layer and just specify:

```
IconComponent: NewIcon
```

The second problem is the following portion of `NewIcon`:

```
<svg
      {...props}
      className="sorter-dropdown"
```

This will cause `props.className` to be overwritten by `className="sorter-dropdown"`. If you were to reverse the order of `className="sorter-dropdown"` and `{...props}`, the MUI class name would get through, but then you would lose any styles that you apply via `sorter-dropdown`. The solution is to combine those two class names:

```
 <svg
    {...props}
    className={`${props.className} sorter-dropdown`}
```

Here's a code sandbox demonstrating this approach: https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-select-icon-0xj079?file=/src/App.js.

Comment: Thank you so much , perfect explanation

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get IconComponent to work, but you could try this:

Use the InputAdornment prop that TextField has in InputProps. The docs have some examples of how to use it here:

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#InputWithIcon.js

https://mui.com/material-ui/api/outlined-input/

For example:

```
<TextField
      select
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      label={label}
      disabled={disabled}
      className={className}
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
      variant="standard"
      InputProps={{
          disableUnderline: true,
          endAdornment: ( // or startAdornment
            <InputAdornment position="end"> // or "start"
              <NewIcon />
            </InputAdornment>
          ),
      }}
      fullWidth
      size="small"
    >
      {withNoneOption ? isNoneOption : children}
</TextField>
```